# getObject operation returning metadata instead of object content from GCP in camel-spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, apache-camel, cloud-object-storage

I have a spring boot application using camel to connect to google object storage to get an object (text or photo).
This is the code I'm running:

```
package footballRestAPIs;


import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.google.storage.GoogleCloudStorageConstants;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

import core.ErrorProcessor;


@Component("ListObjFromGCP")
public class ListObjFromGCP extends RouteBuilder{
    
    
     @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            
         
            onException(Exception.class).handled(true)
            .process(new ErrorProcessor());
            

            rest("/").produces("application.json") 
            .get("selectPhoto")
            
            .to("direct:selectPhoto");

        from("direct:selectPhoto")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange xchg) throws Exception {
                xchg.getIn().setHeader(GoogleCloudStorageConstants.OBJECT_NAME, "kitten.png");
                
            }
        })
        
        .to("google-storage://sagessapp_test?operation=getObject")
.log("${body}");

        }

}
```

In the aplication.properties file I have the following:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:/gcp-credentials.json
camel.component.google-storage.service-account-key=classpath:/gcp-credentials.json
```

and this is what `.log("${body}")` shows:

```
Blob{bucket=sagessapp_test, name=kitten.png, generation=1637310466399682, size=0, content-type=application/octet-stream, metadata=null}
```

Inside the blob I can see the metadata, I did not find any documentation on how to return the content of the object. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Object metadata is returned by default.

Try using the [`alt=media`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) parameter to return the object data:

> By default, this responds with an [object resource](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) in the response
> body. If you provide the URL parameter `alt=media`, then it will respond
> with the object data in the response body.

Comment: Hello @Farid Shumbar, ```alt=media``` cannot be used in apache camel but in the API provided by google cloud platform, I need a solution in apache camel. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Jenny, did you try the URI option `includeBody` set to `true`?  https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/google-storage-component.html#_uri_options

Comment: Hi @FaridShumbar, yes I tried this in the application.properties file ```camel.component.google-storage.include-body=true``` but nothing has changed

Comment: and also I tried this ```.to("google-storage://sagessapp_test?operation=getObject&includeBody=true")``` but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the source code of the Camel Google Storage component, I learned you have to use it as a consumer to retrieve the actual file content.

Doing so as part of a route, you use pollEnrich, so

```java
.pollEnrich("google-storage://sagessapp_test?includeBody=true&objectName=kitten.png")
```